# Filter php 5 input

Tags: php, input

I'm starting studying PHP 5 (I always used PHP 4) and for this, I'm building a small (really easy) CMS.
I saw in the manual that they added functions to filter vars.
My CMS must handle some HTML content for the content of pages.
Are these functions (filter_input, filter_var, ecc..) with sanitize filters enough?
Or do I need to build a deeper custom function?

Comment: that depends on your needs. read up on those filters and see if they fit what you need. If not, build deeper.

Comment: If it's the webmaster who enters the html, you don't need to filter it really. If it's for hmlt written by any user (even logged in ones), you'd need to write a html sanitizer. I personally have used successfully [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's almost always enough to use them. However, depending on each query you do or each page content you show, keep in mind that not-so-special characters can also cause surprises. Briefly,

- If you insert into mysql, quote everything and don't let strings contain unhandled quotes. Use mysql_real_escape_string and his friends.
- If you write into a file, you're safe - mind only what you read back.
- If you put default values in input fields, watch out for the same quote that you use around the "value" property.  Malicious strings will try to close quotes.
- If you output HTML, use html_special_chars to avoid surprises. Greater-sign and ampersand are your enemies if you don't handle them.

Sanitizers will do the rest for you (filtering low characters, etc).

Comment: Why have you told him to use _almost_ **deprecated** (way to vulnerable) `mysql_*_escape_anything` method instead of using PDO????? Use **PDO** for christ sake! or mysqli for that matter

Comment: Since he needs to allow some HTML, html_special_chars is of little help for him.

Comment: mysqli is okay - that's why I said "...and his friends".  PDO is something unnecessary at this level. But okay.

Comment: Jan: generally he was looking for a way to be safe when doing I/O. He will look at html_special_chars and understand when to use it. That's how we learn. But if you have a gun, you can choose to shoot OR not. If you don't, you only have one option :)

Comment: Thank you for you help (and thank you to other's help too!!).
I used PDO for queries, so i understood that i don't need to use mysql_escape_*.
I used the filter function for filtering html from a wysiwyg editor (nicedit), saved into the db and then, when i show the text, i need to use the html_entity_decode() for showing into nicedit!
It seems to work fine, but i don't know if it's secure.
another issue is that i call a constructor with $article = new Article($_POST); and then i use filter into the constructor.
Is it safe or i need to filter the whole $_post BEFORE calling the constructor? TY

Comment: I'm not sure about this constructor thing you're asking since I don't know this Article object.  Depends on what it does inside.  BUT.  When talking about security, the most important rule is "know where your input comes from / where your output goes, and handle them accordingly". Things are not dangerous until you USE them. Input comes to your PHP script - fine. PHP itself must be able to handle it. Then you write it back into the editor - NOW is the time to be careful. Protect only what disturbs your editor. If it's properly written, maybe nothing will. Then you're done.

Comment: Thank you again.
You're right about the constructor, but it simply stores $_POST data into the Article object (by filter and assign info passed by arguments). My question was about the $_POST array used like this:
$article = new Article($_POST); so i call the constructor without any kind of filter, but i filter input inside the constructor.
So: PHP handle $_POST data without risks, if i use it as function argument?

Comment: PHP stores the incoming request into a variable.  While juggling between variables only, you can't get into trouble because a variable (per def) can contain virtually anything. If you use string manipulation, however, it's wise to look for "binary safe" functions but as php doc says almost all of them are. Comparisons, value transmissions and such things are definitely safe. So the answer is YES, you can give your object anything. It's PHPs responsibility and he's doing quite well.